# What color swatch preset to use for preparing graphics for print?

Tags: print-design

I would like to know what color swatch preset should be used to print a design you made on illustrator, so there's no confusion on colors from you to the printing company.

Comment: To help get a useful answer, add a little more detail. What kind of design, for what purpose, and are you using any Pantone colors in the design? The term you're looking for is "color profile."

Answer (score 1):

If you are sending it to a printer, your document color mode should be set in CMYK. It will be as close as you can get to the true color. A color will be read differently in RGB, than CMYK.

Answer (score 1):

Avoiding "confussion" is a methodology and workflow, not only a color swatch.

**1)** You **must** have your monitor calibrated, so you do not see on your computer a happy color that it is not real.

**2)** You must have your proper color settings in your aplications, the correct profile for your region (inks and specifications) and type of paper.

**3)** You can use a physical color system, for example a pantone guide, toyo, etc, depending on your country. But you must have one phisical with you too. You should not rely only on the onscreen preview.

**4)** Use the proper color modes neccesary depending on the type of output. If it is digital or comercial offset print. If it is direct inks or color separations.

**5)** Look for a provider that has consistent color quality.

**6)** You should ask for a **well calibrated** color proof. If the project is small, a digital one could work. If it is a very large project, you can ask for a roll proof.

**7)** You can be "in situ" to authorize any special very last moment adjustments.

**8)** If it is a small digital project you need to make a sample, and go back to edit your project to "correct" the color deviations you percive.

**9)** You need to have a very clear comunication with the rest of the workflow.

It is a bit more than a color mode or a swatch.

Answer (score 0):

For printing CMYK & Pantone colors are recommended. CMYK is the combination color, if you want to print in separate colors better you can design with pantone colors.